# org-html-htmlize-generate-css not generating styles

Tags: org-mode, org-export, htmlize

when I run `org-html-htmlize-generate-css` I don't see any css styles being generated.
I've attached screenshot of what I'm getting. I tried with no configuration thinking I broke it but the effect is the same. Changing `org-html-htmlize-output-type` value has no effect.
I'm trying to acquire css rules for code highlighting in exported html.

[image: this is what I get]

Comment: I think this is a bug in Emacs 28.1 and above, which I have reported at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=61521 .

Try generating the file with emacs 27.2 if you can.

Comment: Actually, 27.2 might not work either. I’m not sure when the bug was introduced.